# Active Model Serializer and multiple meta values

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, active-model-serializers

I am looking at the README for Active Model Serializer and see this example:

```
render json: @posts, serializer: CustomArraySerializer, meta: {total: 10}, meta_key: 'meta_object'

...

{
  "meta_object": { "total": 10 },
  "posts": [
    { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
    { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
  ]
}
```

but I'd like to be able to output:

```
{
  "meta_object": { "total": 10 },
   "sort":[2,1],
  "posts": [
    { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
    { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
  ]
}
```

I'm guessing I need to have two meta objects. Is this possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The normal solution would be to nest the "sort" key itself under the "meta" key ("meta" is the catch-all place for response info that is not a model).  So you would use:

```
render json: @posts, serializer: CustomArraySerializer, meta: { total: 10, sort: [2, 1] }, meta_key: 'meta_object'
...
{
  "meta_object": {
    "total": 10,
    "sort": [2, 1]
  },
  "posts": [
    { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
    { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
  ]
}
```

If your requirements absolutely need the "sort" key to appear at the root, you can do it manually:

```
response_json = CustomArraySerializer.new(@posts).as_json.merge { sort: [2, 1] }
render json: response_json, meta: { total: 10 }, meta_key: 'meta_object'
...
{
  "meta_object": {
    "total": 10
  },
  "sort": [2, 1],
  "posts": [
    { "title": "Post 1", "body": "Hello!" },
    { "title": "Post 2", "body": "Goodbye!" }
  ]
}
```